# SQL count based on timediff and column containing a string

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I'm using SQL Workbench.

```
cust_num    date    notes
1234    2016-02-01  advice
1234       2016-02-01   something else
1234    2016-02-02  order
1234    2016-02-03  order
4421    2016-02-15  advice
4421    2016-02-17  order
4421    2016-02-18  something else
4421    2016-02-24  order
```

I know the above is a bit unclear, but basically, there's 3 columns in the above table. One showing customer_num (customer number), one showing date and one showing a notes field.
From the above, I want to perform two queries. I am newish to this so, I hope this is clear. I'm using SQL workbench.

i) I want to count the number of DISTINCT 'customer_num's that placed an order within 4 days of receiving advice.

So the answer based on the table above would be 3. This is because cust_num '1234' made two orders within 4 days and cust_num '4421' made 1 order. So that totals 3

ii)I want to count the number of DISTINCT customer_num's that placed an order within 15 days of receiving advice. Only stipulation is that I don't want to re-count those from (i) that placed an order within 4 days. I want to exclude them.

So the answer to this would be 1. Customer_num '4421' placed 1 order that was bigger than 4 days but smaller than or including 15 days.

Any help really appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

One method is to use `exists`:

```
select count(distinct cust_num)
from customers t
where exists (select 1
              from customers t2
              where t2.cust_num = t.cust_num and
                    t2.date between t.date and date_add(t.date, interval 3 day)
             );
```

The two queries have the same structure.  You just need to change the condition in the `where` clause in the subquery.

Comment: Gordon thank you for the quick reply.  However there is only one table currently so I've nothing to join to using your exist idea.  Is there a way,  just using the fields in the above table?  I suppose I could create a table  for the purpose of this exist query.  What would I need in the other table,  should it just contain the three columns I've shown above?  Also would you or someone else mind writing your query above again in the syntax exactly as it should appear?  I'm slightly confused by 'select 1 from t t2' etc

Comment: I do understand that t is my table and t is table 2 though.  Also I want to repeat my queries per month based on the date column.  So I will need to add in the WHERE clause something like WHERE date BETWEEN '2016-02-01' AND' 2016-02-29'   SO can you please demonstrate how I would include this also?  Thanks

Comment: @187213 His query uses only 1 table, as you can see he selects from t twice (Gordon I think t is confusing..) So just change it to your table name. t2 is an alias so he will be able to compare between the inner one to the outer one

Comment: Would someone mind writing out assuming my table name is called 'customers'.  I'm confused by this t1, t2 business.  I've used aliases,  but thought you had to use AS to define an alias? Thanks all.